# Create SSH session between Kali Linux to Windows XP

Tags: ssh, terminal, putty

I'm currently using PuTTY to connect Windows XP to Kali Linux which has been very successful. However, for a project I'm working on, I need to connect from Linux to XP (using PuTTY still), but the password is never accepted.

I have tried different programs such as `opensshd` and `freesshd` whilst using the Linux terminal, but every attempt has failed. I'm starting to think that the user isn't being found on the Windows XP machine within the PuTTY or via the terminal.

Comment: You need to setup ssh server on Windows, take a look [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/41560/how-to-get-ssh-command-line-access-to-windows-7-using-cygwin/)

Comment: Wouldn't the freesshd provide the ssh server necessary for this?

Comment: May be you can, I found this [link](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/tr-dojo/set-up-a-free-ssh-server-on-windows-7-with-freesshd/) and even a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zei2DPCnMl4)

Comment: @luke-willmer That's also what I assumed. Both opensshd and freesshd provide the requirements for that, possibly without Cygwin.

Comment: I'll download and setup Cygwin, but I'll also follow the link Kirill-a has posted for freeSSHD

Comment: I've followed the cygwin install tutorial, and attempted again to connect via Kali but now I'm receiving a completely different issue. ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host. I can't tell if progress is being made.

Comment: Try to disable firewall in win xp, if it helps - configure it to allow port 22. Also, can you connect to localhost when on windows machine by running `ssh -v localhost`?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The Firewall is already disabled on the XP vm, but I have added an exception to the default ssh 22 port.
Just tried to connect to localhost on XP, its not accepting the password at all